# Reading a file from the local disk

Tags: python-3.x

I am learner of Python (Python 3.4 on Windows 7). When I am running the following code in pycharm IDE it works fine, but when the same is submitted as a solution in codeeval.com challenge, it gives error  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/Trial/simple.txt'. Why so?. 
what is the correct way of reading a file located on a local disk by the online interpreter( Codeeval submission window).

```
path = "D:/Trial/simple.txt"
file = open(path,"r+")
age = file.read().split()
for i in range(0,len(age)):
    if int(age[i]) <= 2:
        print("Still in Mama's arms")
    if 4 == int(age[i]) == 3:
        print("Preschool Maniac")
    if 5 <= int(age[i]) >= 11:
        print("Elementary school")
    if  12 <= int(age[i]) >= 14:
        print("Middle school")
    if  15 <= int(age[i]) >= 18:
        print("High school")
    if  19 <= int(age[i]) >= 22:
        print("College")
    if 23 <= int(age[i]) >= 65:
        print("Working for the man")
    if 66 <= int(age[i]) >= 100:
       print("The Golder years")
file.close()
```

Comment: Most of the time, the input is supplied via `stdin`

Comment: I suspect that the codeeval interpreter won't allow you to read files. It certainly can't read files from your computer, and it probably won't allow you to read files from the server (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Your chained conditionals will not do what you expect.
`a compare b compare c` == `a compare b and b compare c`.  So `4 == int(age[i]) == 3` is never true and `5 <= int(age[i]) >= 11` == `int(age[i]) >= 11`.

You did not specify whether ages are all on one line or each on a separate line.  Either way, the following should work. Note that one can directly iterate through a list without using `range`.

```
import sys
ages = sys.stdin.read().split()
for age in sys.stdin.read().split():
    age = int(age)
    if age <= 2:
        print("Still in Mama's arms")
    if 3 <= age <= 4:
        print("Preschool Maniac")
    if 5 <= age <= 11:
        print("Elementary school")
    ...
```